RecyclerView, display repeated items when rotating the screen or changing fragments
I am making an application in Android Studio in Kotlin with fragments synchronized with the Faribase platform, in which a RecyclerView and Adapter are made in a fragment to be a list of web pages, everything works fine, but when I turn the cell phone from vertical to horizontal or when I leave the fragment and go back, the elements are duplicated. I don't know what the error is, if you can help me, I think the error is in the Adapter.

class ShareFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var shareBinding: FragmentShareBinding
    private lateinit var shareViewModel: ShareViewModel
    private lateinit var shareAdapter: ShareAdapter
    private var shareVehicle: ArrayList<PaperworkServer> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        shareBinding = FragmentShareBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        shareViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ShareViewModel::class.java]
        return shareBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        shareViewModel.loadShareFromServerDone.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
            onLoadChareFromServerDoneSubscribe(result)
        }

        shareViewModel.loadPaperworkServer()
        shareAdapter = ShareAdapter(shareVehicle, onItemClicked = { onShareItemClicked(it) })
        shareBinding.shareView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ShareFragment.requireContext())
            adapter = shareAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(false)
        }
    }

    private fun onShareItemClicked(share: PaperworkServer) {
        findNavController().navigate(ShareFragmentDirections.actionShareFragmentToLinkTwoFragment(share))
    }

    private fun onLoadChareFromServerDoneSubscribe(shareServerLoaded: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>) {
        shareVehicle = shareServerLoaded
        shareAdapter.appendItems(shareVehicle)
    }
}

Adapter
class ShareAdapter(
    private val shareList: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>,
    private val onItemClicked: (PaperworkServer) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShareAdapter.ShareViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShareViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view_item_share, parent, false)
        return ShareViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShareViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val share = shareList[position]
        holder.bind(share)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{ onItemClicked(shareList[position])}
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = shareList.size

    fun appendItems(newList: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>){
        shareList.clear()
        shareList.addAll(newList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ShareViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        private val binding = CardViewItemShareBinding.bind(itemView)
        fun bind(share: PaperworkServer){
            with(binding){
                titleLinkTextView.text = share.name
                cardShareTextView.text = share.information
            }
        }
    }
}

ViewModel
class ShareViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val paperworkServerRepository = PaperworkServerRepository ()
    private var shareVehicle: ArrayList<PaperworkServer> = ArrayList()

    val loadPaperworkServer: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<PaperworkServer>> = MutableLiveData()
    val loadShareFromServerDone: LiveData<ArrayList<PaperworkServer>> = loadPaperworkServer

    fun loadPaperworkServer (){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val querySnapshot = paperworkServerRepository.share()
            for (document in querySnapshot) {
                val paperworkServer: PaperworkServer = document.toObject<PaperworkServer>()
                shareVehicle.add(paperworkServer)
            }
            loadPaperworkServer.postValue(shareVehicle)
        }
    }
}

screenshot of operation
enter image description here
Error when rotating the screen or moving from fragment to fragment, elements are duplicated
enter image description here
I have tried modifying the adapter but without results. Also, the notifyDataSetChanged() method does not work.

To handle screen rotation check the savedInstanceState  and add this code inside the block
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    shareViewModel.loadPaperworkServer()
    shareAdapter = ShareAdapter(shareVehicle, onItemClicked = { onShareItemClicked(it) })
    shareBinding.shareView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ShareFragment.requireContext())
        adapter = shareAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(false)
      }
   }

